# A Problem with a Attribute for Creating a disclaimer on Exchange 365

Tags: directory, attributes, exchange-server

We are trying to implement a disclaimer with Excnhage 365 and reading some attributes from AD User info like %%FirstName%% , %%LastName% , %%Title%% etc but when we try to read %%Description%% attribute Exchange says ***"The disclaimer text contains an invalid macro name: 'description'."***

We have over 1500 users on AD and we can not move the "Description" data to another attribute because some external softwares like SAP are reading that data also from "Description" attribute.

I made some research and found this. After Exchange Online Microsoft products gave up to read Description attribute because of making a conflict with azure 365 mail description info. If I use CodeTwo software it reads Description attribute info with {Description} code and works fine.

So is there any other way to read "Description" attribute data with Exchange 365? If you have exact same problem or similer and found a solution can you share your ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this via mail flow rule disclaimers, the only way I can think of would be using PowerShell to get the Description value for all mailboxes and then using **Set-Mailbox** for pushing the description into a custom attribute. Then you can use e.g. %%CustomAttribute1%% in the mail flow rule's disclaimer HTML code.
The problem is, I've just scanned my test tenant for the **Description** property and cannot find it anywhere.